# How to generate codes template from selected lines in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, templates

I would like to regenerate codes from selected codes,
for example,  there is a SQL

```
SELECT * FROM TEST_TB
WHERE TEST1 = 'A'
AND TEST2 = 'B'
```

And after highlighting those codes and typing some shortcuts the result would be

```
StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
sql.append("    SELECT * FROM TEST_TB   ");
sql.append("    WHERE TEST1 = 'A'   ");
sql.append("    AND TEST2 = 'B' ");
```

It seems like I should use java templates, but I don't know how to achieve it, can any one tell me how to do it?